# Specify which viewController is pushed by segue?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, segue

Is there anyway to programatically control which viewController is pushed into view when a segue us selected? What I want to do is segue to one of two controllers when a `UITableViewCell` is tapped, one for iPhone4 (960 height) and the other iPhone5 (1136 height).

I could just layout/arrange a single view controller manually to accommodate the extra height. Or I could add a 2nd segue (with another ID) and then use `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in conjunction with `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` to push the correct viewController based on screen height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original question related to a segue that is setup to automatically fire by dragging between a `UITableViewCell` and a `UIViewController` in Interface Builder. Using this method you can only access one `UIViewController` via the segues one-to-one relationship.

You can get round this (and do what I originally asked) by wiring the segue directly from the `UIViewController` that contains the `UITableView` (rather from the cell itself) and then using `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to get the selected cell and perform the required segue. Using this method you can setup as many segues as required, by giving each segue a unique identifier you can programatically control which gets called (and when) by `using -performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`